# I have a stable release with OpenBSD 5.8 built. I'd like to upgrade OpenBSD 5.8 now on stable!

Tags: openbsd, bsd

The new kernel bsd I just copy with scp on the root server /bsd.

scp /usr/rel/bsd base58.tgz man58.tgz vim@10.10.10.10:/ && ssh -l vim 10.10.10.10 && cd / && tar -xzvphf base58.tgz && tar -xzvphf man58.tgz

Is that so right?

Is my OpenBSD 5.8 at the new State of the art:

So OpenBSD 5.8-stable?

Is that so right?

Comment: OpenBSD 5.8-stable (GENERIC) #1: Tue Jan 19 06:51:49 CET 2016
    root@buildsystem.opendns.com:/usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/compile/GENERIC

Comment: The answer is it's ok

Comment: cp /bsd /bsd.old && cp bsd /bsd && cd / tar -xvzpf base58.tar.gz and OpenBSD is up to date

Comment: See the result above